# Trying to figure out coordinates of isoscleles triangle

Tags: circles, triangles, coordinate-systems

[image]

I'm programming some application, which heavily depends of geometry. Let's say, in 2D coordinates system I have i.e. :

```
Bxy = (5,-2)
Cxy = (2,-5)
ABlength = 5.5
```

Now I need `(x,y)` of an A (vertex) point. I'm not mathematician, so please, be gentle. Thank you.

Comment: You can do this with the Pythagorean theorem. Note that with only this information there are two places where A could be (one mirrored across BC relative to the other)

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

We have
$$(A_x-5)^2+(A_y+2)^2=(A_x-2)^2+(A_y+5)^2=(5.5)^2$$

From $$(A_x-5)^2+(A_y+2)^2=(A_x-2)^2+(A_y+5)^2$$, we can express $A_x$ in terms of $A_y$ linearly.

Put this value in  $$(A_x-2)^2+(A_y+5)^2=(5.5)^2$$ to find $A_y$

Comment: How can I express depth of my stupidity about all that equation stuff... I could build Anschütz gyrocompass easier. Please be kind and show me the expression which I can use without brain :(

Comment: You don't need to use your brain. It's Pythagorean theorem.